# How to get selected data from child state to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a flight page with various cards with different route information in each. Within each card I have a select button which is identified by the flightID.

```
   Select(FD) {

 this.state={route:''};

       return (
           <div>
               {FD.FlightID}
            <label>
                <Checkbox id={FD.FlightID}
                          name={FD.FlightID}
                          checked={this.setState.route}
                          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
                />
                <span>Select</span>
            </label>
           </div>
        )
    }
```

The Select method is called within each card.

```
return data.map( FD1 => (

       <Row>
         <Card className="card">
            <Card body className="text-center">

               <CardTitle data-es-label="location"> Location:
                       {FD1.Departure}
               </CardTitle>


                <CardText data-es-label="Price">Price
                        {FD1.price} 
                   </CardText>


             {this.Select(FD1)}

      <CardActions>'
```

How do I access the data of the specific card selected to send to make a booking?

EDIT: 
the handleCheckBoxChange

```
handleCheckboxChange = event =>
        this.setState({ route: event.target.checked });
```

Comment: can you show your whole component?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the data on change? If so try: `onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxChange(FD)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to pass id in onChange method like this

```
<Checkbox
  ...
  onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxChange(FD.FlightID)}
/>
```

Then in parent component you can get your element from data array like this

```
handleCheckboxChange = (id) => {
  const selected = data.find(e => e.FlightID = id);
  ...
}
```

If you want to pass some data through more components you need to read about React context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<Checkbox 
   id={FD.FlightID}
   name={FD.FlightID}
   checked={this.setState.route}
   onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxChange(FD)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much , I will give this a try!